# wcf service with callback fails, probably concurrency issue

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding, duplex

I have a duplex wcf service. the client registers and then the server calls a callback. The callback takes as parameter a list of list of strings. as this can be very large, the list is divided in chunks and the callback is called several times.

Here's the service code:

```
using Shared;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
namespace CallbackService.Server
{
    [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue)]
    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        public static IMyServiceCallback Callback;
        public static Timer Timer;
        public void OpenSession()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("> Session opened at {0}", DateTime.Now);
            Callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyServiceCallback>();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            GenerateListAndCallClient(null, null);
        });
    }
    public static string RandomStr()
    {
        string rStr = Path.GetRandomFileName();
        rStr = rStr.Replace(".", ""); // For Removing the .
        return rStr;
    }
    void GenerateListAndCallClient(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        List<List<string>> theList = new List<List<string>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var innerList = new List<string>();
            theList.Add(innerList);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
            {
                innerList.Add(RandomStr());
            }
        }
        int start = 0;
        int count = 90;
        while(start + count < theList.Count)
        {
            lock (typeof(MyService))
            {
                try
                {
                    List<List<string>> currentList = theList.GetRange(start, count);
                    Callback.OnCallback(currentList);
                    start += count;
                }
                catch (ArgumentException) { 
                    //skip last chunk
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

}

Setting count to 1, everything works fine. The Callback is called 100 times on the client. Setting count to 90 gives the exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user codeAdditional information: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:30'.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Increase the timeout

Comment: wouldnt it be faster to make a call with an array of 90 elements instead of 90 calls with arrays of 1 element each? Plus, I get the exception much earlier than the timeout

Comment: What I imagine is happening is that the client is so busy processing messages that it fails to receive new messages. Can the client signal you when it is ready for more messages?